# What's so special about 0x7f?

Tags: java, long-integer

I'm reading avro format specification and trying to understand its implementation. Here is the method for decoding [long value](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#schema_primitive):

```
  @Override
  public long readLong() throws IOException {
    ensureBounds(10);
    int b = buf[pos++] & 0xff;
    int n = b & 0x7f;
    long l;
    if (b > 0x7f) {
      b = buf[pos++] & 0xff;
      n ^= (b & 0x7f) << 7;
      if (b > 0x7f) {
        b = buf[pos++] & 0xff;
        n ^= (b & 0x7f) << 14;
        if (b > 0x7f) {
          b = buf[pos++] & 0xff;
          n ^= (b & 0x7f) << 21;
          if (b > 0x7f) {
            // only the low 28 bits can be set, so this won't carry
            // the sign bit to the long
            l = innerLongDecode((long)n);
          } else {
            l = n;
          }
        } else {
          l = n;
        }
      } else {
        l = n;
      }
    } else {
      l = n;
    }
    if (pos > limit) {
      throw new EOFException();
    }
    return (l >>> 1) ^ -(l & 1); // back to two's-complement
  }
```

The question is why do we always check if `0x7f` less then the byte we just read?

Comment: `0x7f` is just a cool number that the programmer thought would look pretty damn fancy

Comment: @Michael LOL :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a form of bit-packing where the most significant bit of each `byte` is used to determine if another `byte` should be read.  Essentially, this allows you to encode values in a fewer amount of bytes than they would normally require.  However, there is the caveat that, if the number is large, then more than the *normal* amount of bytes will be required.  Therefore, this is successful when working with small values.

Getting to your question, `0x7F` is `0111_1111` in binary.  You can see that the most significant bit is used as the flag bit.

Comment: Ah... They bitwise or with 0x7f. But what if the long representation will use this flag bit. Like, say `0x6FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @SomeName I don't quite understand what you're asking

Comment: Note that code doesn't in fact read a `long` value (64-bit). The code reads a 28-bit signed value, with the sign in bit 0, i.e. not [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: We use the most significant bit to determine if the next byte should be read. Consider the byte array `6F`, `FF`, `11`, `22`, `33`, `44`, `55`, `66` wich we want to decode to long. First we read `6F` which is less then `7F` so we read more. Next we read `FF` which is more than `7F` so we stop and don't read the rest of the bytes. We lost them?

Comment: @SomeName You haven't lost anything, as that's not a valid value for this encoding.  i.e. if the bytes were encoded properly, this would never occur.

Comment: I feel that this is the same trick used in UTF-8, hence I'm mentioning it here to hopefully help someone...

Answer (score 6):

It's `0b1111111` (127), the largest number possible with a unsigned btye, saving one for a flag.

Comment: i.e. the largest possible *signed* byte value.  In C this is `INT8_MAX`