# What is the meaning of 0x7F in the elf header?

Tags: linux, assembly, elf, file-format, abi

The `elf` header starts like this:

- `0x7F` `0x45` ("E") `0x4c` ("L") `0x46` ("F")

What is the meaning of the first bit, which is `0111 1111`, and if it doesn't currently have a meaning, what was the reason that it was first used? The only thing I can find from the [elf spec](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf) is:

```
Name      Value     Meaning
ELFMAG0   0x7f      e_ident[EI_MAG0]
ELFMAG1  ’E’        e_ident[EI_MAG1]
ELFMAG2  ’L’        e_ident[EI_MAG2]
ELFMAG3. ’F’        e_ident[EI_MAG3]
```

Related, but I still don't quite understand the meaning here: [What's so special about 0x7f?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764797/whats-so-special-about-0x7f).

Comment: `MAG` means "magic". That means those numbers aren't inherently special. They are magic numbers chosen to be hopefully unique enough to identify the file as an ELF file. They could have chosen any other series of bits.

Comment: @kaylum right, but why not just have the magic value be `ELF` ? why the first value? Also, what does the `e_ident` mean -- is that "elf-identity" or something?

Comment: You'd probably have to ask the people who worked at SCO in the '90s why they chose 0x7f, and there may not really be a reason - for all intents and purposes it's completely arbitrary.  The `e_ident` pretty clearly stands for "ELF Identification" given the text on page 1-4.

Comment: 4 bytes is a convenient length because a 32-bit machine can read the whole thing into a 4-byte integer and compare it with the desired value using just one instruction.  So it would be desirable to use one extra byte before or after `ELF`.

Comment: I guess one benefit of 0x7f is it's not a printable character and therefore would be unlikely to appear in a text file, which might otherwise have a chance of starting with `ELF` (e.g. `ELF LORE IN GERMAN MYTHOLOGY`).

Comment: [ELF Header Magic - Why was 0x7F put in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54130387/995714)

Comment: @phuclv sure but there's no answer there -- just some comments and a deleted answer. Perhaps someone can answer and merge the two questions together?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked here is that it has no meaning other than being required as the first byte of an ELF file. (Unlike your linked question where the use of 0x7F in the **Java code** serves a specific purpose.)  The answer to the question phuclv linked is that no one knows the answer. Any byte sequence could've been required.